# How to display float in Sonata admin bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, fieldtype

I've this code in entity

```
/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lng", type="decimal", precision=9, scale=6, nullable=true)
 */
private $lng;
```

in amdin class

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('lng') 
        ...
}
```

It saves in normal precision (`36.747148`), but shows only 3 digits after dot (`36.747`). When I specify the type `text` it looks better but becomes required.
This works

```
        ->add('lng', 'text', ['required' => false])
```

is it the best/right solution? or do I need to change type `decimal` for something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem with required like this:

```
    $form->add('lng', null, array(
        'required' => false
    ));
```

Comment: read please. your solution and `->add('lng')` absolutely identical.
thank you for your attention, but the problem not in this